# How do I use a ntfs drive as location for music, videos etc?

Tags: ntfs, home-directory, directory

I have a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot system, using three drives. Drive1 contains windows, drive2 contains downloads, music, videos and so on, drive3 contains Ubuntu.

I would like to have drive2 mounted automatically (assuming I have to edit fstab), the real question is if there is anyway I can store some (not all) of Ubuntu's "standard home folders" for example have downloads and videos there. Would this be possible? I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your drive2 is auto-mounted, most installs manage to configure that automatically, but you can edit *fstab* as shown here [How to auto-mount ntfs partitions](http://dollopofdesi.blogspot.in/2009/07/loading-windows-partition-at-bootup-in.html)

Once you have drive2 mounted, create folders on that hard drive/partition where you want to store your videos and downloads, and then create *softlinks* or *symlinks* to those folders in your home directory. Like this (type these commands when you are in your home directory)-

`cd ~`

`mkdir /path/to/drive2/mount-point/Videos`

`ln -s /path/to/drive2/mount-point/Videos`

This should work for almost all programs as if you had the *Video* folder in your home directory.

Comment: I went a head and did this, works as intended, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would just change the default download location for your specific browser... I can't really offer much more detail because I do not know what browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the drive where your videos/downloads/documents are, is NTFS. Run this

```
sudo apt-get install pysdm
```

press the windows key in your keyboard. and Type in storage device manager. When prompted give your password. Select your drive2(sda1/2/3) whichever you have your media files on select `assistant`, `mount file-system in read-only mode`, ok. And then apply, on the lower left corner, hit refresh. Now reboot your system.

To change the default folder you must install Ubuntu-tweak like so.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

open ubuntu-tweak via dash

then go to administrators > default Folder locations >

[image: folder-locations]

select which folder you want to change. like the folder Documents then, on the lower right screen, click edit. Select which folders you want to change.

**Example**:

```
Document /media/sda3/Documents
```